# Reading from a file or a big database

Tags: mysql, database, file

I have a list of 100000 products. I wish to store the specs of the products, no search on these specs.

Two ways that I can think of are

1. To store the specs as key-value pair in a mysql database
2. Store the values in a file and just read from there.

Which of the two ways mentioned will be space and read efficient, given I am not going to search on those key-value pairs.

Any other approach to solve the problem efficiently will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Can someone plz edit the question for indentation. I am on mobile.

Comment: Would you access that data for read? If yes, what would be the read access strategy?

Comment: The best solution depends on your use-case, but a suitable alternative might be a specialized [key-value store](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database).

Comment: For read, files will be named as per product id which will be indexed in SOLR

Comment: As I said use case is just to read the file and dump on webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is it for, but in general, why not combine both? ;p Use SQLite which is a database stored in a file, You use it just like any other database in most programming languages, but You don't have to bother with all configuring of regular db systems;

Answer (score 1):

If the *only* thing you need to do is read the file and dump it to a web page then the most efficient thing to do is to **store the HTML web page content in a variable in your application**, populated from a file once when you load the app, and pump it out as required. That way you don't need to do any processing or rendering, any I/O, or anything other than display the content.

However, it's quite likely that you'll want to do *something else* with the data at some stage, for example change it or update it or insert values or delete, and in order to do that you'll need to store it in a way that allows you to edit it. That's where *other* use cases come into play, and you can't really decide that only one use case matters unless it really, truly, does.

Comment: Do you think this model is scale-able ? I have to add new products with their features every now and then. Also, that will need lots of memory.

Comment: That's another use case for you to consider, which was the point of the second half of my answer. If you're reading often and changing rarely, then I'd recommend a buffering database table such as MySQL with InnoDB (especially if you're already using MySQL for other things); it automatically uses RAM to cache data that doesn't change often. If you saved your data to a file on the other hand, you'd need to use an extra bit of technology in order to benefit from in-RAM caching to improve many-read-few-write performance.